# Necessary and Sufficient vs Soundness and Completeness

Tags: logic, proof, proof-of-correctness

I am trying to learn proof. I came across these 4 terms. I am trying to relate all.

```
A: X>Y B: Y<X

Necessary Condition 
             B implies A
Sufficient Condition 
             A implies B
```

And

```
A = { set of statements}  Q= a statement

Soundness 
        if A derives Q then A is a logical consequence of Q
Completeness
         if A is a logical consequence of Q then A derives Q.
```

What is relation between all? 
      Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary / sufficient doesn't have much to do with soundness and completeness so I'll explain the two concepts separately.

**Necessary / sufficient**:

In your example, the two statements are equivalent: `X>Y` if and only if `Y<X`. So it is indeed the case that `B` implies `A` and `A` implies `B`. A better example would perhaps be:

```
A: X>Y+1
B: X>Y
```

Here `A` would imply `B`, i.e. `A` would be *sufficient* for `B` to hold. The other way would not hold: `B` does not imply `A` (since you could have `X=10` and `Y=9` in which case only `B` would hold). This means that `A` is not *necessary* for `B`.

---

**Completeness/soundness**:

This took a while for me to wrap my head around when I first encountered it. But it's really simple!

Suppose you have the following:

```
A = { X>Y, Y>Z }
Q = X>Z
```

Now, soundsess says that we can't reach crazyness by sticking to the statements of `A`. More formally, if `Q` does not hold, it can't be derived from `A`. Or, only valid things can be derived from `A`.

It's easy to create an *unsound* set of statements. Take for instance

```
A = { x<Y, X>Y }
```

They contradict each other, so we can for instance derive `X>X` (which is false) by using proof by contradiction.

Completeness says the dual: *All* valid things can be derived from `A`. Suppose that `X`, `Y` and `Z` are the only variables in the world, and `>` is the only relation in the world. Then a set of statements such as

```
A = { X>Y, Y>Z }
```

is complete, since for any two given variables, `a` and `b`, we can derive `a>b` if and only if `a>b` in fact holds.

If we would only have

```
A = { X>Y }  (and no knowledge about Z)
```

then the set of statements would *not* be complete since there would be true statements about `Z` which we could say nothing about.

---

In a nutshell: Soundness says that you can't come to crazy conclusions, and completeness says that you can reach all sensible conclusions.